# Does it make sense to use an object hash code as a memory cache key?

Tags: c#, caching, hash, memorycache

I'm trying to cache the result of an expensive function in a MemoryCache object.

The MemoryCache requires a key that is a string, so I was wondering if it was valid to do the following:

```
string key = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(myObject.GetHashCode());
if (!_resourceDescriptionCache.Contains(key))
{
    _resourceDescriptionCache[key] = ExpensiveFunction(myObject);
}
return (string)_resourceDescriptionCache[key];
```

It feels odd using a single UTF32 character as the key for a potentially large cache.

Comment: I'm getting an error UTF32 value must be between 0x000000 and 0x10ffff so I guess I can't just convert an Int32 to a char this way.

Comment: Not every single 32-bit value represents a valid UTF32 code point.  Simple, not the fastest but decently efficient would be to use the hex representation of the hash code.  From memory, `myObject.GetHashCode().ToString("X")`.

Comment: 2 years later, I'm embarrassed I ever asked this question. How we grow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends.

There are many cases where using GetHashCode() could cause incorrect behavior:

A hash code is intended for efficient insertion and lookup in collections that are based on a hash table. A hash code is not a permanent value. For this reason:

- Do not serialize hash code values or store them in databases.
- Do not use the hash code as the key to retrieve an object from a keyed collection.
- Do not send hash codes across application domains or processes. In some cases, hash codes may be computed on a per-process or per-application domain basis.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx

If the memory cache happens (or can in the future happen) in a different process or app domain than the code that calls it, you fail the 3rd condition.

> It feels odd using a single UTF32 character as the key for a potentially large cache.

If you are caching enough things, the collision rate on a 32-bit hash can be uncomfortably high due to the [Birthday Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

When caching tens of millions of things, I have used a 64-bit hash called [City Hash](https://code.google.com/p/cityhash/) (created by Google, open source) with good success.  You can also use a Guid, though the memory to maintain keys is twice as large for a GUID compared to a 64-bit hash.

Comment: This is a good point. I'm violating rule #2 - using the hash code as a key for a collection. Now I'm stuck with not knowing how to produce a cheap good cache key. For example, serializing the object would be too expensive.

Comment: How is ToHashCode() currently implemented?  Presumably it acts in a property or combination of properties that should be unique (enough).  You could build your string key by concatenating the string representation of those properties.

Comment: Unfortunately, this class actually deals with Object types, so `GetHashCode()` is implemented in whatever way that object implements it. If the type botches its `GetHashCode()` method, and there are collisions, then collisions will all share the same value of `ExpensiveFunction(object)` (which is like a serializer) - even if they would have produced different results. I do my best to isolate this effect by actually using `key = myObject.GetType() + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(myObject.GetHashCode());`

Comment: @Alain: You are effectively implementing GetHashCode per object type as your hash key. If you are truly dealing with any object, that is probably the best you can do.  If there is any ability to have all objects implement a common interface at least, you could also have them provide a better hash key.  You still run into the issues associated with using GetHashCode() mentioned in my answer (also check the link, there are some other issues that I thought less likely to apply so I did not copy those).

Answer (score 1):

Hashcodes can collide. `return 0;` is a valid implementation for `GetHashCode`. Multiple keys will share a cache slot which is not what you desire... You will confuse objects.

If your code does not work with `return 0;` as the implementation for `GetHashCode` your code is broken.

Choose a better cache key.

Comment: How about: `key = myObject.GetType() + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(myObject.GetHashCode());`, that way types that properly implement `GetHashCode()` are not affected by types which intentionally fail to implement it?

Comment: For some context, `ExpensiveFunction()` is a serializer that reflects on the object to give a preview of its contents in a sort of "Browser" window. It's less important to me that every object has a correct 'preview' and more important that I don't waste too many resources re-serializing each object every time it appears in the object browser.

Comment: (In the previous comment I misunderstood you.) Still, you assume that `myObject.GetHashCode()` is a unique key. If that is actually 100% the case then this will work. `It's less important to me that every object has a correct 'preview'` - your approach will work, then. Even a lossy cache key is ok. I don't fully understand the serialization remarks but maybe you can hash the first 32 bytes of the serialized representation and use that as a key.

Comment: @usr: If the serialization format used has any sort of common header, the first 32 bytes would provide less than ideal input for a hash function (e.g. if every serialized value began with `<xml>`).

Comment: That and a serialized representation happens to be what I'm storing in the cache, so generating it to produce a key would defeat the purpose in this instance.

Answer (score -1):

The memory cache is backed by the normal C# Dictionary. It really isn't much different, other than the fact that it provides expiration

The chances of a collision are 2^32, which is the size of an integer. Even if you do manage to get a collision, the dictionary has safety measures around that (by using the Equals on a collision)

Edit: The key collisions are only handled when a dictionary is given the unaltered key (ex: Dictionary()). In this case, since the MemoryCache uses strings, theres no collision detection.

Comment: `potentially large cache` = potentially high collision rate http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: Collisions in a dictionary are resolved using the more expensive `Equals` method.  When using the hash code as the key to the dictionary hash collisions result in incorrect behavior, not just more expensive computations.  That's a *huge* difference.

Comment: In the code example provided, it uses the object.GetHashCode(), which will likely be pretty unique. And by potentially large, if it's a few million keys, the dictionary will still handle it just fine; there are ~4.2 billion possible keys after all. The birthday problem doesn't apply, unless theres a custom hash generator implemented that only produces a limited key set.

Comment: @Dan: With just 100,000 objects, there is a 68% chance of at least one hash collision.  With 1,000,000 entries the probability is very close to 100%.  http://lazycackle.com/Probability_of_repeated_event_online_calculator__birthday_problem_.html